# How can I access login action response in webview in react native?

Tags: react-native, authentication, webview

I want to reach the response returned after login in webview. But after a lot of research, I couldn't come to a conclusion.

1. Welcome screen. Here I am redirecting to the webview by clicking the button.
2. Login screen(Webview). I need to reach the response returned after logging in here.

How can I access requests and responses in webview? Or what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

you can use injected script to send data to webview ,and  postMessage to send data back to react native app

```js
//This sends data from WebView to React Native
...
<script>
  window.postMessage("Sending data from WebView");
</script>
...


//In order to get data the was sent from WebView use onMessage prop on <WebView>
...
<WebView
   ref="webview"
    injectedJavaScript={`
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#f4f4f4';
 true; `}
    onMessage={this.onMessage}
/>
  
onMessage(data) {
  //Prints out data that was passed.
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: I can't interfere with the code of the webview page. I just need to get the response after pressing the login button on the login page in the webview.